# Xcode View Hierarchy debugger won't rotate views on mouse drag

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview-hierarchy

I'm running Xcode 10.2.1, on MacOS 10.14.3 (Mojave), compiling and running a default single view iOS application in the simulator.  When I click on 'Debug View Hierarchy' I can see the views, switch to 3D, zoom, spread and filter with the on-screen buttons, select views in the 3d pane or in the tree view.  In almost every respect it all works as expected.  but...

**Drag to rotate is not working.**

I've double checked in Reveal.app and the behaviour is the same: no drag-to-rotate.

I'm using a Magic Mouse 2 but have checked with a standard mouse.  Drag to rotate is broken when debugging view hierarchies.

Has anyone seen this behaviour, or have any suggested solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tsk, I'm old enough to know better: fixed with a reboot.

Why this happened is another question.  I'd be curious to know if there are any system components that need restarted to reenable without a reboot.